# Oracle: Is there a way to put exception handling into a function and just reference that function inside procedures?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, functions

If you were going to write 10 procedures that all have the same exceptions, you'd want to just reference the procedures defined somewhere else, right?

You can call a function inside a procedure

```
create or replace procedure P
    a_variable_name number;
begin
    a_variable := a_function('a parameter');
end;
/
```

And i imagine you'd have to pass the result of your procedure into the function. Like

```
if X procedure executed correctly, then do nothing
if Y error, do the Y exception handling
```

Is such a thing possible? If not, how do oracle users handle writing 10 different procedures that all use the same exception handling? Like, are there any tips and tricks besides just copying and pasting those exceptions and hoping you'll never have to change all 10 of them if you have to change one thing?

Comment: A _function_ is not the proper object.  While you can jump through hoops and make a function do a lot of things, just because you can does not mean you _should_.  The purpose of a function is to return a value.  Think to_date.  What you want to do can be accomplished, but is properly done with another procedure, not a function.

Comment: @EdStevens ok, is there another thing I can use to refer to a set of exception handling statements?

Comment: Sure. Just like I said .."What you want to do can be accomplished, but is properly done with another procedure, not a function".  Write a stored procedure and call that.  You just need to be careful that when you start trying to handle and report exceptions yourself (instead of letting Oracle do what it does) that you don't end up swallowing critical debugging information that oracle would have reported if you had let it handle things. Nothing worse than a user getting error message "Severe error. Contact systems administrator". with no additional info to report to said admin.

Comment: @EdStevens ohh i see. I misunderstood. That's helpful, thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of the exception handler you want to reuse?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I was looking at how to extract data to csv in oracle and this page suggests writing a million exception handling statements. So if i wanted to extract to multiple csv files, would i need to copy and paste the same exception handling statements to all of those procedures? I'm looking at the "Custom Solution (PL/SQL)" section here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files

Comment: I'm not keen on Tim's approach here, which is to list every single exception from `utl_file` into one big exception handler at the end. I think you should check for specific errors when opening the file, when fetching etc. Have a look at https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml

Comment: @WilliamRobertson The fact that you gave me your opinion and linked to your website is insanely helpful. Thank you! I also had no idea there was a magic `/* csv */` command! I would actually like to automate creating a csv, like this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=automate-the-generation-of-sql-query-output-to-csv If I wanted to use `DBMS_SCHEDULER`, i couldn't use `/* csv */` , right?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Could I use the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` with your package? Also, i'm completely new to this. This is my first project, and i'm super unfamiliar with exception handling and i haven't even attempted to acquire a systematic process for figuring out what exceptions could be thrown. I'll need to do that sometime in the future. Right now my goal is to put together a minimal viable product (a database) for my personal use. Would you recommend that I just use your package? Like, is the exception handling there pretty general, if such a thing exists?

Comment: @ellie-lumen correct, `/* csv */` is a SQL Developer feature. [SQL\*Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42236970/230471) and [SQLCl](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlcl-format-query-results-with-the-set-sqlformat-command#csv) have something similar, but they are client tool features and not part of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* have a procedure that checked for various values of `sqlcode` or `sqlerrm` and performed whatever actions you have in mind based on those, and called that procedure from your exception handler passing the filename and directory object name. However, I don't think that would be a neat solution.

If the problem is trying to reproduce the (quite old) [Oracle Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files) approach for handling `utl_file` exceptions in multiple procedures, don't do that. It just copies every single exception from the manual and dumps them all into a monumental end-of-procedure exception handler, regardless of context.

When you open a file, you should use an exception handler to ensure that it opened OK, otherwise you can report that you couldn't open file x in folder y. For example (from [www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml)):

```
begin
    l_file :=
        utl_file.fopen
        ( filename => p_filename
        , location => p_directory
        , open_mode => 'w'
        , max_linesize => 4000 );
exception
    when utl_file.invalid_operation then
        raise_application_error(-20007, 'File '''||p_filename||''' could not be opened in directory '||p_directory||' ('||k_dir_path||')', TRUE);
    when utl_file.invalid_path then
        raise_application_error(-20008, 'File location '||p_directory||' ('||k_dir_path||') is invalid.', TRUE);
    when utl_file.invalid_filename then
        raise_application_error(-20009, 'Filename '''||p_filename||''' is invalid.', TRUE);
end;
```

Similarly, when you write to a file you could use exception handlers to ensure that write errors are reported clearly with appropriate details.

Or, centralise all CSV writing operations in a single package like the one I linked to, where you just pass in a refcursor and the file details and it does the rest.

Comment: Yeah, I think your package executes the general idea I was looking for. I haven't worked with packages yet, but I'm trying out your package and I'm learning so many things right now! I'm so glad i asked this question on SE instead of just writing a bunch of this code: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/274063/why-does-sql-developer-suggest-a-different-format-for-a-procedure-that-wroks I really appreciate your help!

Comment: One final question. I want to make a procedure of nested procedures from your package for all the CSVs I want to generate and have the one procedure be performed automatically at set periods of time. Is there a problem with doing this? It seems that some people on the internet are not fans of nested procedures, but I don't understand why.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to structure your code so that a procedure calls other procedures, that sounds fine, unless the whole calling tree becomes overcomplicated.

Comment: Yes, a procedure would call other procedures. Cool, I just wanted to see if my code that I was excited about was a terrible idea for some reason that I'm not aware of. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hello again! I tried using your package, but it stopped working. Is it compatible with CAST statements in procedures? Would you mind taking a look at my question if you have time? https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/274535/213511